# jQuery AJAX not passing values to AJAX call

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Edited to make it easier to understand.

Ok, so the problem is that jQuery does not pass value to a certain PHP file in order to run a DELETE query and remove the content you requested to be removed from database.

The script works great with one other file which requests the information from MySQL and loads it via AJAX call to a php file.

The problem might be in this script the actual AJAX

```
   $(".removeNote").live('click',function() {
      $("#qpbox-content").show();
      $("#qpbox-overlay").show();
      $("#qpbox-loader").html("<img src='http://www.ajaxload.info/images/exemples/4.gif' />");

      var xhr = $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "_class/delete_notes.php",
         data: "ajax=1&nid=" + this.parentNode.id,
         success: function(html){
            $("#qpbox-utm").html(html);
            $("#qpbox-loader").html("");
         },
         error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {$("#qpbox-loader").html(errorThrown);}
      });
   });
```

this is the part from which the code above should get the value

```
<p style="margin-bottom:3px;" id="$nid">
         <div id="$nid" style="float: right; padding: 4px;cursor: pointer;" class="removeNote">
         <img src="$icon_sys_delete" alt="remove note" title="remove note"/>
         </div>
         </p>
```

the value is noted as $nid

and this is the actual delete part

```
<?php

include '../object/db.class.php';

if($_GET['ajax'] == '1') {

$nid = $_GET['nid'];

$query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM notes WHERE nid = '$nid'");
echo "Note removed!";

}

?>
```

So thats it...

Comment: filter out your question from too much context/code will let others more easy/willing to give a answer for you.

Comment: Is this being echoed or is it plain HTML?
<p style="margin-bottom:3px;" id="$nid">
If it's not being echoed using PHP, then you'll need to wrap $nid in php tags.
I'd also try echoing out your query to see if it is resolving properly.  It sounds like $nid is either blank or null.

Comment: @espradley its being echoed as PHP $entry_display .= <<<ENTRY_DISPLAY

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
 data: "ajax=1&nid=" + this.parentNode.id,
```

to

```
 data: "ajax=1&nid=" + jQuery(this).closest('div').attr('id')
```

Ive assumed that the "div" is the one that you are looking for to get the "id" value.

The problem with your code snippet is you have mixed JQuery with raw javascript. If you wanted to do it your way(without using jquery to get the value), you could use

```
 data: "ajax=1&nid=" + this[0].parentNode.id,
```

Comment: yes its the div from which the value must be passed i tried your suggested approach jQuery(this).closest('div').attr('id') and still no luck, the PHP echos that the Note has been deleted but it still in MySQL

Comment: In that context `this` is not a jQuery wrapped element.

Comment: found the problem it was not jQuery the jQuery was 120% correct. The problem was in MySQL Query fixed now

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `<p>` does not contain `<div>`. So, the `parentNode` of `.removeNote` is not the `p` tag. Also, `id` attribute is supposed to be unique. I would remove `nid` from `p` and simply use `this.id`.